# Augemented Reality integration in iOS App

Tags: ios, iphone, augmented-reality, vuforia

I want to integrate the `Vuforia sdk (Augemented Reality)` in my new iOS app. Is there any steps or video guide for step regarding to integrate into iOS app?

Guide me, I have been searching a lot, but not getting any single clue.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: might help you: https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/sdk/ios, https://github.com/MasDennis/RajawaliVuforia

Answer (score 0):

[migrating-your-ios-sdk-project](https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/migrating-your-ios-sdk-project)

Steps:

Reference links:https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/getting-started-ios-native-sdk

1. Place your unarchived Vuforia sdk in your development
   directory/folder.
2. Add libQCAR.a framework in your project.
3. Set libQCAR.a framework path in XCode build setting "Other Library
   search path"
4. Set Vuforia header classes folder path from unarchived Vuforia sdk
   in your development directory/folder in "Other Header paths"

Tutorial

[augmented-reality-tutorial-for-ios](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3997/augmented-reality-tutorial-for-ios)

this video link help you

[Vuforia Augmented Reality SDK for iPhone](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nMOZ4JPAGw0)

sample app

https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/sample-apps

Comment: i know this but i want to make a new project and add that sdk into my new app... i dont want to play with his code./. is there any tutorial for do this..